# Как можно исправить проблему с задним фоном?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, как можно исправить проблему с задним фоном?
Если просто открыть сайт, без белого выступа, а если открыть инспектор, то появляется белая полоска.

```
margin:0;
padding:0;
background: url(../img/background.png) no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
```

[[image: Тут при нормальном режиме]
[image: Тут при открытии инспектора]

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, часть кода и разметки `html`, желательно таким образом, чтобы можно было воспроизвести проблему. Иначе мы никак Вам не сможем помочь.

Comment: в том же div-э что картинка случаем нету еще чего то с белым фоном? при открытии инспектора экран уменьшается и этот блок смешается на картинку

Comment: Я исправил ошибку, спасибо за уделенное время!